# How can my Discord Bot assign a Role to new Users?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

First im new to Coding, that means i mostly Copie and Paste things.

To my problem: i do exactly things like in Videos, switch on "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT" in the Discord Dev portal and so on. **But my Bot won't assign a Role after someone Joins my DC.**

*My code looks like a mess BUT! the function i wanted first that the Bot reply "pong" after i type !ping worked finaly after many hours of re-coding stuff*.

***here my code:***

```
global.Discord = require('discord.js')
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { on } = require('events');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const prefix = "!";
const fs = require('fs');

const token = "my token";

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'anfänger');     

    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('930264184510361670').send(`Welcome <${guildMember.user.id}> to out Server!`)
});

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}! Im on ${client.guilds.cache.size} guild(s)!`)
    client.user.setActivity({type: "PLAYING", name: "Learning Code"})
});

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('messageCreate', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
    const command = message.content.split(' ')[0].slice(prefix.length).toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'is'){
        client.commands.get('is').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }
});
 
client.login(token);
```

Comment: "i mostly Copie and Paste things" I highly recommend you change your strategy if you plan to be able to create and develop on your own. There's an abundance of free resources online to teach you JavaScript and NodeJS. Regarding your question, have you checked `welcomeRole` is undefined, does your console emit an error when the code runs?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes i should first "learn" but it does so much fun. I dont get any Errors in my Terminal. Thing is the Bot reply works just fine, i got it to work by myself. how do i undifine 'welcomeRole' ? ( i changed the position of my code a bit but this doesnt work either. Do i have to to create an module.exports for this?

Comment: if `welcomeRole` is returning undefined that means that a role with the name `member` does not exist. Double check your roles and rolenames

Comment: So basically `let welcomeRole` defines my Role in DC as 'anfänger' and this is a variable for: `guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);` right?

Comment: i just updated the codes postion and the Role Name according to my discord.

Comment: I did it, had missing Intents and partials.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! there it is
you spelled `guildMember` as `guildmember`

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async guildMember => {
    var i = "930263943597928508";
    let role = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === i);
    guildmember.roles.add(role); //here replace guildmember with guildMember
})
```

Comment: if it where that easy huh :( i have another Code updated you might check this out.

`client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'anfänger');     

    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
})`

Do i have to set a new collection for this? like `client.guildMember = new Discord.Collection();`

Comment: I did it, had missing Intents and partials.

Comment: wow that took you so long

Comment: only want that you and other reading this knows that this Topic is done. did it the day after i wrote this down here. Sry for taking this long but you didn't see the problem either...